# How can I authorize custom function to use Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, custom-function

I'm trying to create a custom function in Google Sheets that generates an array with de brazilian holidays, to automate it in another formulas that calculates data intervals considering holidays. But this code is generating that error message:

> The script is not allowed to perform this action. Required Permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds) (line 4).

I have already allowed the Calendar API in the Google API Console and created the credentials, but I don't know if I need to use them in my code or if there's some Google problem.

Here's the code I tried:

```
function FERIADOS() {
  var cal = "pt.brazilian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com";
  var calendario = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cal);

  var dtini = new Date('January 1, 2019 00:00:01 -0300');
  var dtfim = new Date('December 31, 2020 23:59:59 -0300');

  var eventos = calendario.getEvents(dtini, dtfim);

  for (var i = 1; i < eventos.length ; ++i) {
     var event = [];
     event[i] = eventos[i].getStartTime(); 
  }

  return event;
}
```

Comment: You cannot. As the error message clearly indicates. So instead you must write a macro or menu-driven function, as that gets invoked by the current / installing user and associated with that user account and its permissions.

Comment: Even creating a macro it doesn't works. I think it's because the Calendar Service isn't allowed on custom functions, so the only way I could use to improvise is creating a new collumn and inserting the array on each line, and later using the interval. I'm goint to create too in the code a time-driver trigger, so the interval will be always updated. But thanks by the help. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calendar Service is not one of the Services available to custom functions. Read [Guidelines for custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions) and [Using Apps Script Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Comment: Thanks, I just improvised by inserting the array content in a interval on a sheet, so it works.